# Appending a Series as a Row Data Frame Pandas (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,
                     'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                     'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
                     'D' : np.array([3] * 4,dtype='int32'),
                     'E' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"]), })
```

This looks like

```
    A   B           C   D   E        
0   1   2013-01-02  1   3   test    
1   1   2013-01-02  1   3   train   
2   1   2013-01-02  1   3   test    
3   1   2013-01-02  1   3   train
```

I want to append a "Totals" row for numeric columns and put in "Totals" in Column E.

So what I have is:

```
totals=pd.Series('Total', index=['E'])
totals = df2.sum(numeric_only=True).append(totals)
```

which yields

```
totals
A        4
C        4
D       12
E    Total
dtype: object
```

So if I try

```
df2.append(totals, ignore_index=True)
```

I get

```
A   B                       C   D   E
0   1   2013-01-02 00:00:00 1   3   test
1   1   2013-01-02 00:00:00 1   3   train   
2   1   2013-01-02 00:00:00 1   3   test    
3   1   2013-01-02 00:00:00 1   3   train
4   4   NaN                 4   12  NaN
```

My question here is why doesn't column 'E' have a "totals" and why is it NaN?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but slight change works.

```
total = df2.sum()
total = total.append(pd.Series('Total', index=['E']))
df2.append(total, True)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `categories` with category `Total` by `categories=["test","train","Total"]`.

I think you get `NaN`, because this category does not exist.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,
                     'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                     'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
                     'D' : np.array([3] * 4,dtype='int32'),
                     'E' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"], 
                                           categories=["test","train","Total"])})


totals=pd.Series('Total', index=['E'])
totals = df2.sum(numeric_only=True).append(totals)
print df2.append(totals, True)
   A          B  C   D      E
0  1 2013-01-02  1   3   test
1  1 2013-01-02  1   3  train
2  1 2013-01-02  1   3   test
3  1 2013-01-02  1   3  train
4  4        NaT  4  12  Total
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will get a NaN in column E unless it is an existing category (i.e. 'test' or 'train').  So first we must add your new value `Total` to the categories, and reassign the result back to the column.

After doing this, your original method will work.  However, I believe this is more straightforward approach:

```
df2['E'] = df2.E.cat.add_categories('Total')
df2.ix[len(df2)] = df2.sum()
df2.iat[-1, -1] = 'Total'

>>> df2
   A          B  C   D      E
0  1 2013-01-02  1   3   test
1  1 2013-01-02  1   3  train
2  1 2013-01-02  1   3   test
3  1 2013-01-02  1   3  train
4  4        NaT  4  12  Total
```